# Example of compare editor

Tags: java, eclipse, compare, eclipse-rcp

I am totally new to the Eclipse RCP platform. Are there any example how to use compare editor?

I have created a view, and now I want to add there compare editor to compare text data.

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart {
    public static final String ID = "rcp.views.myview";

    private TreeViewer treeViewer;

    public MyView() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        CompareViewerPane pane = new CompareViewerPane(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FLAT);
            //?????????????????
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not found a way to set up own view with compare pane (my poor experience in swt and jface, and mostly due to lack of working rcp examples). I have found a way (thanks to http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F) to open compare pane using static methods of CompareUI class.

One more thing which I struggled with for a long time is setting up compare panes editable (actually I checked out from cvs eclipse compare plugin source code and ran it in debugger to find place where panes are set editable). On the http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_compare_editor%3F they say that if one wants to create an editable compare pane, he just needs to set editable flags in CompareConfiguration, may be this have changed over time, but `don't believe` to it. Currently (eclipse indigo) CompareConfiguration has editable flags set by default and to enable editable capability for compare viewers you have to implement `IEditableContent` interface in your compare data source (CompareTtem that is described http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_Compare_dialog%3F).

That is all for now.

Comment: Also look here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/compare_beyond.htm. And finally, you will probably want to use resources (files) as your objects to compare as that is what the compare stuff is used to dealing with. There is a section on working with resources here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt.htm